# How to implememt a dynamic sized shell with a ScrolledComposite in eclipse SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, scrolledcomposite

I have created a Shell and added a ScrolledComposite to it that contains a Text as its content. But I want the shell to change the size dynamically based on the content size. My implementation is as follows

```
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
    sc.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).hint(200, 200).create());  

    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);

    Composite top = new Composite(sc,SWT.NONE);
    top.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.swtDefaults().numColumns(1).create());

    StyledText styledText = new StyledText(top, SWT.NONE);
    styledText.setText(text);

    StyleRange style = new StyleRange();
    style.start = 0;
    style.length = text.indexOf(":"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    style.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;     
    styledText.setStyleRange(style);    


    sc.setContent(top);
//  shell.setSize(sc.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    sc.setMinSize(top.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    sc.pack(true);
    shell.setVisible(true);
```

When I uncomment the commented line in above code, shell is resizing based on content, but unable to achieve scrollbar in this case.

I want to get scrollbar as well if content is beyond certain limit. If the content is within the limit, I do not want the shell to have extra blank space.

Can someone help me here ??

Comment: `StyledText` supports scrolling itself, it doesn't need to be in a `ScrolledComposite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StyledText` supports scrolling itself there is no need to using `ScrolledComposite`:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);

shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

text.setText(....);

shell.layout();

Point size = shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);

shell.setSize(Math.min(size.x, 100), Math.min(size.y, 100));

shell.open();
```

Instead of using `shell.pack()` just call `shell.layout` and then `shell.computeSize` to see what the unscrolled size would be. Adjust the size if it is too large and call `shell.setSize`.

Comment: How can I use StyledText to show scrollbars only when the data exceeds certain limit ? As in for eg, if text is more than 100 lines, then scrollbar should appear. Is this possible ?

Comment: This code does that for me on macOS. Possibly it is not so clever on other platforms (which I can't test).